# How long can zooxanthellae survive on their own, after being expelled from coral after a bleaching event?

Tags: plant-physiology, life, algae

So many sites (and books and journals and such) discuss how long different types of coral can survive without their dinoflagellate algae (zooxanthellae), but...

How long can the poor little symbiotic algae survive on their own after being unceremoniously ejected from their coral hosts?

Aren't most of them (the algae) obligate mutualists?

Can they float around in 'suspended animation' indefinitely?